# Auth Provider - LinkedIn - User Info Endpoint URL?

Tags: auth-provider

I'm having trouble determining what the "User Info Endpoint URL" should be when setting up a Auth Provider on a Salesforce org for LinkedIn.

I have correctly set up the Authorize Endpoint URL and the Token Endpoint URL for LinkedIn on Salesforce.. but I can't seem to find documentation anywhere for what the User Info Endpoint should be set to in Salesforce..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

To clarify things, here is what I use for a Google Open ID Connect Auth Provider in Salesforce, as well as what I have so far for the LinkedIn one.

**Google:**
Authorize Endpoint URL  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

Token Endpoint URL  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

User Info Endpoint URL  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo

**LinkedIn:**
Authorize Endpoint URL  https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress%20

Token Endpoint URL  https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken

User Info Endpoint URL  ?????????

Comment: Have you seen this documentation https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api?

Comment: Yes I have, still having issues getting the Auth Provider set up properly. Tried "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~" and it was telling me invalid request.

Comment: And are you including the access token in the request using this atypical parameter name https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/oauth2-oauth2accesstoken-instead-simply-accesstoken?

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to which of those URLs I should be including that.. I edited my original question to show what I've been using for the URLs.. If I don't include an User Info Endpoint URL, it will take me to LinkedIn and ask me to login, then it takes me back to salesforce and in the URL gives me the following error: **AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Endpoint_URL&ErrorDescription=Could+not+generate+endpoint+URL**

Comment: If I add "https://www.linkedin.com/v1/people/~" as the User Info Endpoint URL in salesforce, it will take me to LinkedIn and ask me to login, then it takes me back to salesforce and in the URL gives me the following error: **AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=Remote_Error&ErrorDescription=invalid_request**

Comment: Sorry I wrote some OAUTH2 stuff where I was making the requests from my own code and so could use whatever names for parameters I liked. Presumably you don't have that control. As I understand the process, the access token must be included in the user info request as it is used as the security mechanism. That parameter is usually named access_token, but for LinkedIn they have chosen to name it oauth2_access_token. If the Salesforce mechanism you are using does not allow you to provide a name for that parameter, you may be sending access_token when you need to be sending oauth2_access_token...

Comment: Yeah that's what was confusing me is that when using a Salesforce Auth Provider, I do not have control over setting those parameters. I believe that it properly sends the access token using the salesforce mechanism - just missing the last part.

Comment: I'm suggesting that Salesforce - if it has access_token hard coded - may not be able to interoperate with LinkedIn - assuming it will only accept oauth2_access_token.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a little time trying to figure out how to get LinkedIn to work with the OpenID auth provider as well. While it does support OAuth2, it turns out that LinkedIn doesn't seem to support OpenID. On one of the webinars recently they mentioned that (Safe Harbor) LinkedIn Auth Provider might show up at the end of the year (similar to how Facebook has its own Auth Provider).

For now, you can use the Janrain Auth Provider (which can handle LinkedIn), or you can build it yourself.